# What's the fastest way to clear a std::list of dynamic objects?

Tags: c++, performance, list, stl

I have a list defined like:

```
std::list<int *> m_ilist;
```

and I add `int`s to the list:

```
m_ilist.push_back (new int (x));
```

I want to destruct the vector and delete the memory that was allocated for each element.

Which one is better:

1. Doing a loop through the list, calling delete on each iterator. After this calling clear():

   ```
   for (...) { delete *it; } m_ilist.clear ();
   ```
2. Doing a loop but calling erase on the iterator:

   ```
   for (...) { delete *it; m_ilist.erase (); }
   ```

*Better* would be defined as quicker /  faster / less processing.

Thanks.

Comment: Or use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)/[`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and just call `clear`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I don't see the C++11 tag in that question, so those would get compiler errors.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating `int`s?  Unless you want to be able to use NULL as a sentinel value, and none of the legal `int` values can be used instead, then it's just wasting time and memory.  Even if you need a sentinel, using boost's optional library or a `std::pair<bool, int>` will be more efficient.  Then you can simply clear the list when done.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Oh please make that an answer!

Comment: int was just an example...probably not the best choice. The question was more about the speed of iterating and erasing vs clearing afterwards.

Comment: @NicolBolas most of us assume that "C++" means "the newest stable/official version of C++", just like with all other technologies discussed on SO.

Comment: @Kos: C++11 isn't close to fully available from any compiler vendor, let alone proven stable.  But, Joachim's comment could have benefitted from "(if these C++11 features are available, else boost or other equivalents)".

Comment: @Kos: Is there an actual C++11 compiler available (one that **fully** supports the standard)?

Comment: @bitmask: If you want to get technical, there was only ever one C++03 compiler that **fully** supported the standard. The one from EDG, which implemented `export`. Even so, support for C++11 today is still scattershot and fragmented.

Comment: True. However `std::unique_ptr` has been around for quite some time in both GCC and Clang, even MSVC has afaik, why not recommend it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmark it. More importantly, benchmark it *in your particular application*. There is no point in us testing a synthetic runtime of both versions, when your mileage *will* vary, depending on what you do afterwards.

The bottleneck is the nasty freeing and mallocing that goes on behind the curtains. Depending on the memory allocation pattern the remainder of your program exhibits, you will most likely get different results.

Having that said; The difference is most likely negligible, so my gut says go for the second and save one loop if in doubt.

---

Edit: Note that if you're really concerned about speed, use an `std::vector<int>` instead of an `std::list<int*>`. The difference will be significantly larger than between the options you list.

Edit 2: If you use an `std::vector` make sure to use variant 1 (with `clear` instead of many `erase`s). In this case it *does* make a huge difference. If the elements are really huge (as opposed to `int`) you may want to actually put pointers (or smart pointers, for that matter) into the vector to minimise the copy overhead.

Comment: Thanks - we normally use `std::list` mainly because we need a `list`.

Comment: BTW what's your scenario for actually using a `std::list` of ints with strong ownership, that actually requires you to hold references not objects? I mean, I can imagine why `list` not `vector` (because you need both O(1) insertion and maintained order), but why not just `std::list<int>`?

Comment: The `list` is used simply. The data is put in in the order it arrives (hence push_back) and then the user of the data iterates over all the data (without modify or random access). The use of `int` in the above is just an example.

Comment: Interestingly, doing this with `vector` and not `list` almost doubles the time. Using a small test programme - alloc 100000 int's, iterate then erase - `vector` takes 1.2s, `list` takes 0.5s. Doing option 1 vs 2 - option 1 takes 0.52s vs option 2 takes 0.55s. So not much in it. Thanks.

Comment: Another oddity, using option 2 with `vector` takes 0.39s. This would seem like there is a large overhead to `erase` ops on vectors.

Comment: @user626201: Yes, `vector::erase` will be slow, since it must move all the later elements. For a `vector`, you'd want to empty it with `clear()` afterwards.

Comment: With `vector` you can also erase from `rbegin()` to `rend()`, so you never need to move elements. Still, `.clear()` is more readable.

Comment: @user626201: Note that you can further improve .39s if you know (or can roughly guess) the number of elements before inserting them. Have a look at `std::vector::reserve`. In your scenario, there is no reason to use `std::list` over `std::vector`! This also makes your question disappear, because for vector you have to use version 1 (as your experiments show).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest approach is not to delete it at all.  This might be a strange answer, but there are some ways to not delete it, yet still not having memory leaks.

You could try to pool your integers.  Instead of allocating and deallocating integers, create a pool of integers.  This saves you from allocating and deallocating memory over and over again, at the cost of doing your own management (which integers are already in use, which aren't).  How complex this management is depends on the situation.  In some cases it's sufficient to simply hand out the integers one by one, and deleting all of them at the end.  See if this trick might help in your case.

You could also try to not clean up the list in the main thread, but in a separate thread.  Start a 'cleanup thread' in the beginning of your application, and when the list needs to be cleaned up, pass the list to the other thread (use events, critical sections and a queue to pass the list from the main thread to the cleanup thread.  Now the cleanup thread can cleanup the list and deallocate the memory while the main thread keeps on running doing the important stuff.

Finally, use your imagination.

Comment: +1 for the pooling suggestion; you may want to rephrase the background-thread idea, because that's basically a GC, and there's plenty of them to ready-to-use for C++.

Comment: Thanks - however, the use case is in an embedded memory constrained system. Hence, once the data structure closes, all memory needs to be released for other processes. However, I do like the idea.

Comment: Thanks CAFxX.  Can you give me some examples of GC's for C++ that do their delete in a second thread?  I like the idea but I have no experience with these GC's in C++.